# change the size of an image in a table

Tags: javascript, html

I am dynamically creating a table with js and appending an image to every cell.
I am trying to resize my image using Jquery, but for some reason the resizing is not working.

my method is

```
  function table(){
    var rows = 8; 
    var cols = 8;
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    for(var r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
      var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
        for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++)
    $('<td></td>').appendTo(tr)
    .append($('<img/>').
    attr({src: './img.png'}),
    height(50),
    width(50));
     tr.appendTo(table);
    }
```

anyone know what I am doing wrong?

In addition, I also tried to resize my td, but I couldn't figure out how to resize it. any suggestions?

thanks

Comment: try changing the width and height attributes, like you did with src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set this using the `css( )` jquery function:

```
function table(){
    var rows = 8; 
    var cols = 8;
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    for(var r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
      var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
        for (var c = 0; c < cols; c++) 
            $('<td></td>').appendTo(tr)
                .append($('<img/>')
                .attr('src','./img.png')
                .css({'height':'50px','width':'50px'}));
        tr.appendTo(table);

    }
}
```